# I flagged some comments as obsolete and they didn't get removed. Was I not supposed to?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

[passport.socketio's passport "Failed to deserialize user out of session". But passport in my main app (with the same key) deserializes just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492459/failed-connection-to-socket-io-no-session-found-but-session-does-exist)

As much helpful the comments were, they made the original question I asked so different that the comments themselves are now (I thought) obsolete, and so I flagged them as such. But since they're not gone yet, I was wondering if I wasn't supposed to do that?

Comment: The flags haven't been handled yet.  We have 1.2K flags in the queue, you've got to give us some time to process the flags

Comment: You can view the progress of your flags here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1266650 (Profile -> Helpful flags)

Comment: Comment flags usually aren't handled with the highest priority, when I flag them they can take up to a day to get handled.

Comment: Sorry, but, **what's the rush**? Why are you in such a hurry to see them removed?

Comment: @Oded No rush at all, I genuinely thought they were obsolete, as the question now is something completely different (if you can see the revisions). I even deleted my own comments. I just thought the comments were now off-topic and distracting from the main question. And actually, this was my first time trying out the "flagging comments as obsolete" feature, and since my edit suggestions are usually accepted almost instantly, I was genuinely worried if I shouldn't have done that..

Comment: Comments flagged as offensive are usually removed rather quick, at least judging by my personal experience. The other flags are probably a lower priority and thus get handled slower...

Comment: You have done fine, the problem is that the flag queue is not empty. Not even close, so it takes time to get to newer flags.

Comment: @l4mpi - that doesn't mean you should mis-flag. Sure, offensive/spam will get handled faster (both due to higher visibility and due to the relative harm to the community they have). Not saying you are advocating that - just saying that flagging should be as accurate as can be.

Comment: @Oded of course I'm not advocating that, just pointing out that it depends on the type of flag. The few (~20) comments I flagged were mostly offensive and were removed pretty fast - which makes sense IMO as these are the ones that should be handled first. A comment that's "too chatty" doesn't need to be deleted immediately :)

Comment: @laggingreflex: Somehow, there's lots of irony when combining your nick and this questions topic. Double so when considering rob-reviewers for edit-suggestions ;-)